# Angular 8 - Assign class property inside MergeMap

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular8, mergemap

I'm using MergeMap to make nested http calls in my Angular 8 app. However, my requirement is to assign a property of my model inside MergeMap as shown in below code.

```
onFormSubmit(author, email, website, comment) {
    let user = new BlogCommenter();
    let userComment= new BlogComment();
    user.Name = author;
    user.Email = email;
    user.Website = website;
    userComment.Comment = "Some Comment";
    userComment.PostId = 1;
    userComment.ParentId = 2;
    let status = this.userService.postBlogCommenter(user).pipe(
      mergeMap(commtr => { userComment.UserId = commtr.Id; this.commentService.postComment() })
      );
  }
```

Of-course the code written inside mergeMap isn't working, the error TypeScript shows is "Type void isn't assignable to type 'ObservableInput'".

My requirement is to assign the user object's **ID** property to the BlogComment object's **UserId** property post which make the second http call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword `return` is missing, for starters, that's why "void isn't assignable...".

```
mergeMap(commtr => { 
    userComment.UserId = commtr.Id; 
    return this.commentService.postComment();
});
```

(And yes, subscribe to make anything happen).